# Windows Azure Service Client

Tags: android, azure

I'm trying the my Azure Mobile Service. Below is the code to make a new ToDo item entry. The sample Android code shows how to create a mobile client. I added it to the `onCreate` method as mentioned in the example. 
But the insert always fails. I always get an exception which says `com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.`

`mClient` does get initialized. But, `mClient.mCurrentUser` is null. Not sure if this is a problem.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient("https://myservice.azure-mobile.net/",
                "slkerjasfi234eSomePrivateKey", this);

        Item item = new Item();
        item.setText("Awesome item");
        item.setComplete(false);
        mClient.getTable(Item.class).insert(item,
                new TableOperationCallback<Item>() {
                    public void onCompleted(Item entity,
                            Exception exception,
                            ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                        if (exception == null) {
                            ShowMessage("Success");
                        } else {
                            ShowMessage("Failed");
                        }
                    }
                });

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it looked like the key (parameter 2 in `MobileServiceClient` constructor) was incorrect. That is how I had downloaded it though. It happened again today and I manually fixed the key and it worked for another service. Believe it was the same issue here. To view your key, you go to your service in Azure and click Manage Keys at the bottom.